# SoftEther Radius authentication issue

Tags: docker, authentication, radius, softether

I set up a SoftEther with Docker. I then installed and set up a Radius server with daloRADIUS. I can't create a user in Radius that will create the same user in SoftEther.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a wild card user (ie *) and then your radius connection will look for any available account associated with the group that you configured to allow VPN access for on the radius server. You can do this using the server manager or the cmd tool:

[soft ether vpn server user setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY2Vk.png)

Or using the server

```
UserCreate *
```

And ensure the authentication is set to radius.